# Why did some of Israel's kings include partial years as part of their reign while others didn't?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, chronology

King Ahaziah of Israel became king in Jehoshapat's 17th year(1 Ki 22:51) and died in his 18th year(2 Ki 1:17), yet he's said to have reigned for 2 years. Consequently, we must understand his 2 "years" being made up of 2 partial years.

King Pekahiah of Israel, on the other hand, is said to have become king in Uzziah's 50th year(2 Ki 15:23) and died in his 52nd(2 Ki 15:27). Including part of year 50, shouldn't Pekahiah have been attributed 3 years, rather than the 2 provided by 2 Kings 15:23?

In Ahaziah's case, the author includes partial years as part of his reign. Pekahiah does not recieve the same luxury. Why the difference in reckoning?

I asked a different but related question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132126/which-jehoram-became-king-first-ahabs-or-jehoshapats)

Comment: In short because I don't have time now, it's because the kings of Israel and the kings of Judah counted their years differently. See here for some more information: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33272/how-do-we-determine-the-nature-of-the-reign-of-the-kings-when-the-numbers-dont/128511#128511

Comment: @Harel13 I'm aware of the (probable) possibility that Judah used accession reckoning while Israel used non-acccession. The issue is: Ahaziah & Pekahiah are both northern(Israelite) kings.

Comment: Doesn't matter. What matters is what time of year they ascended the throne. Achaziah could have ruled for only three months, but if he ascended at Adar, he would have been considered a 2-year king because the scholarly consensus is that Israelite kings counted years from Nissan. Pekachiah likely ascended at a time after Nissan of Uzziah's 50th year. His first year was from post-Nissan ascension to Nissan of the 51st and his second year was from Nissan of the 51st to Nissan of the 52nd. He would have passed away sometime before Tishrei (Judahite ascension month) of the 52nd year.

Comment: @Harel13 if I'm understanding correctly, your explanation is not that some kings got partial years and others(in Israel) didn't but that these differences are caused by the fact the Israelite kings counted their regnal year from a different date?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.